# Android: Unable to retrieve the Uri of a folder

Tags: android, uri

I have an app which allows the user to pick a folder via the Android file picker `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and then creates a ZIP file in the selected folder which eventually will be shared.
I can retrieve the selected folder Uri via `Uri uri = data.getData();` in the OnActivityResult function.

This works, an example Uri with my SD card selected looks like this: `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/15E6-0F1A%3A`

Now I need to temporarily store a ZIP file in the applications cache folder, before sharing it out. But I struggle to get to the Content Uri of the cache folder?

What I thought I need to do is the below:

```
File filePath = new File(this.getCacheDir(), "");
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", filePath);
```

And the send the Uri on to the function which creates and shares the ZIP file, but calling `FileProvider.getUriForFile` with a folder leads to a crash of the application. `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

As soon as I create a file in the cache folder and use this file handle to call `FileProvider.getUriForFile` I get a proper Uri:

```
File filePath = new File(this.getCacheDir(), "");
File newFile = new File(filePath, "tmpFileName");
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", newFile);
```

So it seems like FileProvider.getUriForFile can't handle folders?

I searched up and down but somehow everything I found was specifically about files, where I need a folder Uri. I have tried alternatives like DocumentFile and File but all I ended up with is "file" Uris' and not "content" Uris.

Therefore my question is, does anyone know of a way to get a content Uri from a folder, or more specifically, how can I get the **content** Uri of `this.getCacheDir()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can retrieve the selected folder Uri via Uri uri = data.getData(); in the OnActivityResult function.

That is not a folder. It is a document tree. Note, in particular, that it does not have to represent a directory on a filesystem.

> Now I need to temporarily store a ZIP file in the applications cache folder, before sharing it out

Create a `File` object pointing to your desired destination file in `getCacheDir()`, then use standard Java file I/O to copy or create your ZIP file using that `File` object. Note that no `Uri` values are needed for this.

> So it seems like FileProvider.getUriForFile can't handle folders?

Correct.

> And the send the Uri on to the function which creates and shares the ZIP file

The `Uri` that you share will point to the ZIP file. You do not need a `Uri` that somehow points to `getCacheDir()`. You can use ordinary file I/O to create the ZIP file, without involving a `Uri`.

> how can I get the content Uri of this.getCacheDir()?

There is nothing that is part of Android that really supports this concept, and you do not need it.

Comment: Thanks for your response @CommonsWare, really appreciated. Confirming that I did hit a dead end surely saves me from wasting more time with this.
I was hoping I can reuse my existing ZIP-and-send routine which I went through great pains with to get from "document tree" delivered by the file picker to eventualy a ZIPoutputstream.
But in that case I'll duplicate the ZIP-and-send logic based on File objects, will surely be a lot simpler anyway.